# EF Core calling EntityState.Modified then making async http request disposing db context

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, ef-core-2.1

code causing issue

```
var cats= await _animaldb.Cats.ToListAsync<Cats>();

foreach (var kitty in cats)
{
 kitty.LastReq = DateTime.Now;
 kitty.DailyReqCount = cats.DailyReqCount + 1;
// make HTTP request here to some endpoint async
 var data = await _restOps.GetJsonAsync("url");
// perhaps thread is being disposed ?
_animaldb.Entry(kitty).State = EntityState.Modified;// err 2nd iteration 
}

_animaldb.SaveChanges();
```

db context is added to startup.cs

```
services.AddDbContext<AnimalDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
```

Edit: adding getJsonAsyn

```
public class RestOps
{
    private readonly ILogger<RestOps> _logger;
    private readonly Animaldb _animaldb;

    public RestOps(ILogger<RestOps> logger, Animaldb animaldb)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _animaldb= animaldb;

    }

    public async Task<string> GetJsonAsync(string url, bool randomUserAgent = false)
    {
        var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
        var client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3000);
        UserAgents userAgent = await GetRndUserAgent();
        var userAgentStr = string.Empty;

        var resultUserAgent = randomUserAgent ? userAgentStr = userAgent.Name : userAgentStr = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36";
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", resultUserAgent);
        // Make a list of web addresses.  
        // GetAsync returns a Task<HttpResponseMessage>. 
        string content = null;
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            // Retrieve the website contents from the HttpResponseMessage.  
            content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            content = "Failed to get:" + url;
        }
        return content;
    }

    private async Task<UserAgents> GetRndUserAgent()
    {
        UserAgents userAgent = null;
        Random r = new Random();
        var id = r.Next(0, 40);
        using (_animaldb)
        {
            userAgent = await _animaldb.UserAgents.FindAsync(id);

        }
        return userAgent;
    }
}
```

Error message:

```
Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a 
context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to 
use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur 
if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a 
using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the 
dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances
```

Note: I am using db context in a for loop/ modifying and saving the entries ok, earlier in the code!

EDIT: I did not say i was making a async http req sorry!

TL;DR,

Seems the issue to do with thread being disposed, I could use a non async http req, I'd prefer to be able to keep it this way if possible as http requests make take a while to complete.

Thankyou for looking, Any ideas ?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `var data = await _restOps.GetJsonAsync("url");` from the code to test whether it is working or not?

Comment: Hi, yes I have checked and it works fine, without the async http req, there's not much point in pasting the whole controller as it's a layer or 2 behind i'll add all the DI & constructors and the http call method

Comment: Damn, I just spotted the mistake, will wait a bit for someone to answer. as it's no fun answering your own question!

Comment: What is it? You made the asynchronous method  synchronous?

Comment: no,, it's the using when it ends it disposes of the db context

Comment: Which using block? I suspect something like that. You can answer your own question.

Comment: take a look at the bottom of of the last class posted

Comment: Using block in the `GetRndUserAgent()` method?

Comment: yup that one..you actually helped by asking me to paste it here, thats when I spotted it! layers deep!, thx for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the usings statement in GetRndUserAgent(), this is disposing of db context!!!

```
    using (_animaldb)
    {
        userAgent = await _animaldb.UserAgents.FindAsync(id);

    }
```